# Why does Oracle report "ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis" for my SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
CREATE TABLE "ITDEV"."WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "FLOW_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PATHID" NUMBER, 
    "FILENAME" VARCHAR2(400), 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "MIME_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "DOC_SIZE" NUMBER, 
    "DAD_CHARSET" VARCHAR2(128), 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "UPDATED_ON" DATE, 
    "DELETED_AS_OF" DATE DEFAULT to_date('01-01-0001','DD-MM-YYYY') NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_UPDATED" DATE, 
    "CONTENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(128), 
    "BLOB_CONTENT" BLOB, 
    "LANGUAGE" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "SECURITY_GROUP_ID" NUMBER, 
    "FILE_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "FILE_CHARSET" VARCHAR2(128), 
     CONSTRAINT "WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJ_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT), 
UNIQUE ("NAME")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT )  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  LOB ("BLOB_CONTENT")STORE AS BASICFILE (
  STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT));
```

output

```
SQL Error [906] [42000]: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

Comment: [Divide-and-conquer algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm)

Comment: Please try to use useful titles here. Questions that have a title that is little more than pleading for help can be closed, because they lack clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`STORAGE IN ROW` should be `ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW` (see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adlob/using-oracle-LOBs-storage.html#GUID-D4B9A527-6DF8-4451-B88B-B973E961D9F7)).

```sql
CREATE TABLE "ITDEV"."WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$" 
(
    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "FLOW_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PATHID" NUMBER, 
    "FILENAME" VARCHAR2(400), 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "MIME_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "DOC_SIZE" NUMBER, 
    "DAD_CHARSET" VARCHAR2(128), 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "UPDATED_ON" DATE, 
    "DELETED_AS_OF" DATE DEFAULT to_date('01-01-0001','DD-MM-YYYY') NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_UPDATED" DATE, 
    "CONTENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(128), 
    "BLOB_CONTENT" BLOB, 
    "LANGUAGE" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "SECURITY_GROUP_ID" NUMBER, 
    "FILE_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "FILE_CHARSET" VARCHAR2(128), 
     CONSTRAINT "WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJ_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
       USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
       STORAGE(
         INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
         PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
         BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
       ), 
     UNIQUE ("NAME")
       USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
       STORAGE(
         INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
         PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
         BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
      )  ENABLE
)
  SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(
    INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
    PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
  )
  LOB ("BLOB_CONTENT")
  STORE AS BASICFILE (
    ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW
    CHUNK 8192
    RETENTION 
    NOCACHE
    LOGGING 
    STORAGE(
      INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
      BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
    )
  );
```

Comment: Wow, amazing!! all I had to do was add ENABLE before store in row. Thank you very much